# Show libraries found by ./configure before building?

Tags: autoconf

Is it possible to get autoconf based build systems to show the libraries it found and will link against, before building the software? As-is my current workflow is:

```
$ cd tps-source-dir
$ ./configure --options-i-know-to-pass
$ make
$ DESTDIR=~/install make install
$ find ~/install -name "*.so*" -exec ldd \{\} \;
Crap it found the wrong version of libfoo, try again.
```

It would be *really* nice to learn exactly which libraries it was going to use *before* spending hours compiling a large package.

Comment: First, read Stephen Kitt's answer. AUTOCONFIG does only what the programmer tells it to do, which usually--but not always---creates a suitable `Makefile`, and caches various bits of information in other files, such as the `config.status` file. This may not be enough for your desired situation. You will need to read the documentation provided by the source package, and/or examine the Makefile to see what it is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `configure` scripts do this already, but there’s no generic way to get `configure` itself to output a nice list of the libraries it’s found.

However all the information is available in `config.status` and `config.log`. You’ll get the libraries found by running

```
grep LIBS config.status
```

and the relevant flags, if any, using

```
grep LDFLAGS config.status
```

All this is stored as compiler flags, so you can also search for `-l`, `-L`, and `-I` for headers.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, it looks like all the packages I'm building this week simply check if a library exists in the configured path and if is a suitable version (or has the features needed), but don't record the path of that library, just use what the linker provides them with `-lfoo`. But it is helpful to know when to stop looking for features that don't exist :)

Comment: I might try adding a simple hello_world target to the Makefile, and see how much customization that needs from project to project to ensure it is built with the same options as the real targets.

Comment: Or setup an inotify watch for the first .so that is built, so I can abort earlier if needed.

Comment: Yes, that’s quite common – if `-lfoo` works, there’s no need to dig any further (from `./configure`’s perspective). You can look for a `--with-foo` option if necessary, that usually provides a way to override the library location used.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably look for and pass --with-foo for all non-system libraries, as use of LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems hit or miss depending on the project.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a runtime configuration variable, you need to specify `LDFLAGS` for build-time library settings.